# Center a table in the page

Tags: html, css

I wrote this HTML/JavaScript code but I can't center the table in the page. I've tried both with align=center and with margin in style. But nothing seems to work. Even putting the table into a div.

Edit: Better description: I'm trying to take four picture from IP cameras (small pictures) and make them appear into a fullscreen browser centered and maximized on the page.

This is the code:

```
<body style="margin:0; background-color:black;">
<table style="height:100%; background-color:black; position:fixed;">
    <tr>
    <img height="50%" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAGUExURQAAAP///6XZn90AAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAKSURBVBjTY2AAAAACAAGYY2zXAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" name="Camera1"/>
    <img height="50%" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAGUExURQAAAP///6XZn90AAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAKSURBVBjTY2AAAAACAAGYY2zXAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" name="Camera2"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <img height="50%" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAGUExURQAAAP///6XZn90AAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAKSURBVBjTY2AAAAACAAGYY2zXAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" name="Camera3"/>
    <img height="50%" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAGUExURQAAAP///6XZn90AAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAKSURBVBjTY2AAAAACAAGYY2zXAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" name="Camera4"/>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>

<script language="JavaScript">
//<!--

function reloadImage()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var Camera = new Array()
    var Camera1 = 'http://192.168.10.219/cgi-bin/wappaint?camera_no=0&animation=0&name=aa&password=11&time=1346851800&pic_size=2'
    var Camera2 = 'http://192.168.10.219/cgi-bin/wappaint?camera_no=1&animation=0&name=aa&password=11&time=1346851800&pic_size=2?1346851972719.719'
    var Camera3 = 'http://192.168.10.219/cgi-bin/wappaint?camera_no=2&animation=0&name=aa&password=11&time=1346851800&pic_size=2?1346851974247.247'
    var Camera4 = 'http://192.168.10.219/cgi-bin/wappaint?camera_no=3&animation=0&name=aa&password=11&time=1346851800&pic_size=2?1346851975678.678'

    if (document.images)
    {
        var image1 = new Image;
        var image2 = new Image;
        var image3 = new Image;
        var image4 = new Image;

        image1.onload = function () { document.images.Camera1.src = image1.src; }
        image2.onload = function () { document.images.Camera2.src = image2.src; }
        image3.onload = function () { document.images.Camera3.src = image3.src; }
        image4.onload = function () { document.images.Camera4.src = image4.src; }

        image1.src = Camera1 + '?' + now.getTime();
        image2.src = Camera2 + '?' + now.getTime();
        image3.src = Camera3 + '?' + now.getTime();
        image4.src = Camera4 + '?' + now.getTime();
    }
    setTimeout('reloadImage()',1000);
}

setTimeout('reloadImage()',1000);
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use inline css. It's bad, bad and bad.

Comment: Don't know why, but if I use <td>, it brings the pictures to their original size.

Comment: @jurgemaister What should I use instead of that? Why it is "bad"?

Comment: It's hard to read, it's hard to maintain, and it isn't [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself). That's why it's considered bad practice. Besides, your code isn't valid. I think you might have the wrong approach your problem. Try to include a few lines on what you are trying to achieve with this code in your question.

Comment: Added some detailed description of my target.

Answer (score 2):

You should learn to write `HTML` first. Markup for Table goes -

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>You img tag</td>
    <td>You img tag</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>You img tag</td>
    <td>You img tag</td>
  </tr> <!-- And so on -->
</table>
```

You completely missed `TD` in your code

[**Here is the answer**](http://jsfiddle.net/kbSny/) to your question

**Edit:**

When you are adding `img` tag in `TD` use `width and height attributes`, it will solve the resizing issue -

```
<img src="img/imageName.jpg" width="400" height="400" alt="" title="" />
```

And hey, I used the learning thing because you posted the question here so I assumed you are already working on HTML. Never mind! Why don't you try with [**HTML Fundamentals**](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/html-one-o-one) 
This will help you understand HTML very well! :)

Comment: If I put the <td>, it resize the image to a smaller one and can't find any way to have the same result with <td>. If you have an answer to this just write it; If I had known how to write HTML I would not have asked here.

Comment: Don't worry, it's fine, this is the first time I code in HTML but I can't lose this much time learning from the beginning, I just needed a quick help for showing the factory IP cameras in the office.

Comment: I'll try as you suggested and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

There is no td specified. Add td after the tr and give `align="center"` to the table tag". 
And remove the `position:fixed` if it is really not necessary

Check the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/2QnE9/2/

Comment: If I put the <td>, it resize the image to a smaller one and can't find any way to have the same result with <td>. I need the position fixed for getting rid of the scrollbar. I already tried with align=center and it's not working.

Comment: If you dnt put the then it is not at all valid code. Give the width to the table according to your image size.

Comment: The images are small 352x288, but I'd like them to fit the whole screen in four. I tried putting weight=352 and the <td>, it doesn't center it and shows me the images in the original resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it a fixed width and set margin-left and margin-right to auto and remove the fixed position from your table

EXAMPLE

```
width:500px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Comment: If I remove the fixed, then it shows the scrollbar, is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PV8Cx/embedded/result/)**

Here is the `CSS`:

```
    #mytable
    {
    position:fixed;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    //set margin-left and margin-top to get it to center.
    }
```

Comment: This is not centered on the screen… It instead puts the top-left corner of the table in the middle and the table grows outward to the right and down.

Comment: @thirdender Ya got it , I think he will then have to adjust margin-left and margin-top properties to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, but there are other ways to center an object on the screen which don't require knowledge of the object's dimensions. Great article at [CSS Tricks: Centering in the Unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/).

Comment: Can I put my table into a div with the style suggested by the link? Will it work?

Comment: @Stefano Yes you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table align="center" style="height:100%;background-color:black; position:relative;">
    <tr><td>
    <img height="50%" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAGUExURQAAAP///6XZn90AAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAKSURBVBjTY2AAAAACAAGYY2zXAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" name="Camera1"/>
    <img height="50%" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAGUExURQAAAP///6XZn90AAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAKSURBVBjTY2AAAAACAAGYY2zXAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" name="Camera2"/>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <img height="50%" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAGUExURQAAAP///6XZn90AAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAKSURBVBjTY2AAAAACAAGYY2zXAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" name="Camera3"/>
    <img height="50%" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAGUExURQAAAP///6XZn90AAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAKSURBVBjTY2AAAAACAAGYY2zXAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" name="Camera4"/>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried the whole code? Maybe it's because of other mess I've done.

Comment: @Stefano Can you tell me how to display table in your code? You have used any html control as a container for display table

Comment: Sorry Harry, I didn't get it, what are you asking me?

Comment: I've tried both with div and without. Doesn't work in both case.